# python3-psutil error when trying to install terminator in kali linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I am trying to install `terminator` on Kali Linux 2022.2 and get the following error.

```
$ sudo apt install terminator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: python3-psutil : Depends: python3 (< 3.9) but 3.10.4-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone give me instruction on how to solve this issue?

I tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before trying to install `terminator`.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux security distribution geared towards various information tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the Kali tools.

Comment: Rather than installing many tools onto Ubuntu I would much prefer to get this one tool installed on Kali and learn something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully upgrade your Kali release to 2023.3.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

Once rebooted, you can install `terminator`:

```
sudo apt install terminator
```

Comment: Will this work in a VM? Sorry I forgot to mention that this is a Kali install in a VM in Virtual box.

Comment: @ToOldToGame Of course.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code that you have provided, there is a line saying: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: python3-psutil : Depends: python3 (< 3.9) but 3.10.4-1+b1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Kali Linux likes to tell about every error that occurs during the installation of any tool or package the user tries to install. In your case, it has told you about the package that is preventing the installation of your intended tool because it is in a broken state. So to fix these types of errors, you can either install that package separately by just coping the package name from the terminal in which, in your case, it is `python3.10.4-1+b1` or you can simply run this command `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, the last line `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` indicates that your system has multiple broken packages. So, in your case, I would recommend that you run this command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` instead of installing that single package of Python3 your system suggested, however, if you want to experiment with it, then you can run `sudo apt install python3.10.4-1+b1 -y`. After that try to install Terminator. In case, you face an error stating that some packages are `missing` not `broken` then I suggest you run this command: `sudo apt --fix-missing install`. I hope this information helps solve your problem with the installation of Terminator.
However, @[GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153195/gad3r) has also shared the right solution with you.